# Keystroke not monitored after clicking on buttons

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, keydown

I have made a game where the character moves using wasd. In the same form on the right side there are some buttons and other controls but when they are pressed the character wont respond on keydown events. How can I solve that?

Comment: Step 1: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

This is because Windows has the concept of "Focus". (Read up on it.)  Key events are only sent to the control which has focus, and at any given time only one control within the form has focus.  You probably have some control which renders your character, and you have placed your key event handlers on that control. When the form first pops up, you give focus to the rendering control, so everything is fine. But as soon as you click on another control, that control takes focus, so your rendering control does not have focus anymore.

Solution:

After a button gets clicked, use `SetFocus()` to return focus to your rendering control.